# Resetting ngModel values to default Model?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am using ngForm, and at the bottom of my form, I have a reset button. When I click reset, the entire form resets, but does not restore the initial model values established in my ts model.

How do I ensure that the model below is present when I hit the reset button instead of the entire form clearing out?

in ts file:

```
 model = {
  color: 'Red',
  size: 'XS',
  age: '34'
};
```

html:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="region">Select Color</label>
                <input id="color" class="form-control" name="color"
                    [(ngModel)]="model.color" [typeahead]="colors" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="region">Select Size</label>
                <input id="size" class="form-control" name="size"
                    [(ngModel)]="model.size" [typeahead]="sizes" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="age">Select Color</label>
                <input id="age" class="form-control" name="age"
                    [(ngModel)]="model.age" [typeahead]="ages" required>
        </div>
```

Comment: Use a simple method to reset all the values in the model object

Answer (score 3):

Its quite simple, just pass default value's object in `ngform's reset` method, for further reference this [app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-58qtwe).

```
  resetFormWithDefaultValues(){
    this.slForm.reset(this.defaultValues);
  }
```

Comment: SO this works great! However, this reset only works when the code reads:      <input id="age" class="form-control" name="age"
                  ngModel [typeahead]="ages" required> vs       <input id="age" class="form-control" name="age"
                    [(ngModel)]="model.age" [typeahead]="ages" required>   . So now, I am unable to have my form set with the initial values, but it resets great! Any ideas on how to keep this reset functionality but also allow me to have default values of model?

Comment: Thanks @JHogan, However, I use the Reactive forms to have better control over them.

Comment: is there a way to do this with ngforms?

Comment: its a type of form in angular, more information can be obtained here https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms